# Mysql: 3 types of users, row with multiple entries, cannot separate

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an old mysql data base (not created by me). It has 300k users, users are either flagged with flag=0, flag=1 or flag=1 and flag=0. The latter means that user was flagged in the past and currently is no longer flagged. The table looks like:

```
user_id | log_data | action    | data    |
001     | 1-1-2002 | flip-flag | flag=0  |
002     | 2-2-2003 | flip-flag | flag=1  |
002     | 2-3-2003 | flip-flag | flag=0  |
003     | 3-3-2003 | flip-flag | flag=1  |
```

I am trying to create a list containing only the users that were flagged in the past and are no longer flagged  (flag=1 and flag=0, user_id=002 in the table above) I tried:

```
select user_id, data
from table_name
where (data = 'flag=1' and data = 'flag=0')
limit 50;
```

but it does not return any result. Doing:

```
select user_id, data
from table_name
where data = 'flag=1' limit 50;
```

gives the list of all users flagged with flag=1 (current flagged and past flagged). Does anybody know what to do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I'm thinking aggregation and `having`:

```
select user_id
from table_name
group by user_id
having max(case when data = 'flag=1' then log_date end) <
       max(case when data = 'flag=0' then log_date end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the following query that you wrote will never return any data - the same row cannot have data = 'flag=1' and data='flag=0' which is why you'll have to use aggregation or a self join to get this right.

```
select user_id, data
from table_name
where (data = 'flag=1' and data = 'flag=0')
limit 50;
```

Another solution (probably less effective than Gordon's version)

```
select t0.user_id          
from table_name t0
where (select t1.logdate from table_name t1 where t1.user_id = t0.user_id 
       and data = 'flag=1' order by 1 desc limit 1) > 
      (select t2.logdate from table_name t2 where t2.user_id = t0.user_id 
       and data = 'flag=0' order by 1 desc limit 1)
group by t0.table_name
```